# analog clock using tkinter on python but as soon as i run it it stops after 1 second

Tags: python, tkinter

```
#imports
import tkinter as cl
import time
import math

#creating window
window=cl.Tk()
window.title("analog clock :3")
window.geometry("400x400")
 
#formula for how the clock
""" sign(radius(t)) = x/r
x = r  * sign(radius(t))

cos(radius(t)) = y/r
y = -1 * r + cos(radius(t))"""



#customising canvas
canvas=cl.Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

#importing images
bg=cl.PhotoImage(file="D:\PythonProjects\dial.png")
canvas.create_image(200, 200, image=bg)

#making the hands of the clock
sec_hand_len = 90
min_hand_len = 80
hour_hand_len = 60
center_x = 200
center_y = 200

sec_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + sec_hand_len, 200 + sec_hand_len, width=1.5, fill="red")
min_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + min_hand_len, 200 + min_hand_len, width=2, fill="black")
hour_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + hour_hand_len, 200 + hour_hand_len, width=4, fill="black")


# defining func. and adding time

def live_clock():
    hour = int(time.strftime("%I"))
    mint = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    sec= int(time.strftime("%S"))
 

    sec_x = sec_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(sec * 6)) + center_x
    sec_y = -1 * sec_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(sec * 6)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(sec_hand, center_x, center_y, sec_x, sec_y)

    min_x = min_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(mint * 6)) + center_x
    min_y = -1 * min_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(mint   * 6)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(min_hand, center_x, center_y, min_x, min_y)

    hour_x = hour_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(hour * 30)) + center_x
    hour_y = -1 * hour_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(hour * 30)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(hour_hand, center_x, center_y, hour_x, hour_y)

canvas.after(1000, live_clock)

live_clock()
window.mainloop()
```

---

thats my code but as soon as i run it it stopped after 1 second

i tried making a clock but it stopped working after 1 second
keep in mind i am super super new and i would really appreciate any help since this is my project for 11th grade cs :)

i had issues with the code before this but i managed to figure them out and fix them on my own but i cannot seem to figure out how to fix this.
as soon as i run the code the tkinter window open and the second hand moves once but it stops and doesnt move again, i thought maybe the seconds hand had the problem but i waited a minute and the minute hand didnt move either so idk what to do now please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the provided code is that the function live_clock() is called only once after a delay of 1000 milliseconds using canvas.after(1000, live_clock). This is why the clock moves only once and then stops.

This might work:

```
#imports
import tkinter as cl
import time
import math

#creating window
window=cl.Tk()
window.title("analog clock :3")
window.geometry("400x400")
 
#formula for how the clock
""" sign(radius(t)) = x/r
x = r  * sign(radius(t))

cos(radius(t)) = y/r
y = -1 * r + cos(radius(t))"""



#customising canvas
canvas=cl.Canvas(width=400, height=400, bg="black")
canvas.pack()

#importing images
bg=cl.PhotoImage(file="D:\PythonProjects\dial.png")
canvas.create_image(200, 200, image=bg)

#making the hands of the clock
sec_hand_len = 90
min_hand_len = 80
hour_hand_len = 60
center_x = 200
center_y = 200

sec_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + sec_hand_len, 200 + sec_hand_len, width=1.5, fill="red")
min_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + min_hand_len, 200 + min_hand_len, width=2, fill="black")
hour_hand = canvas.create_line(200, 200, 200 + hour_hand_len, 200 + hour_hand_len, width=4, fill="black")


# defining func. and adding time

def live_clock():
    hour = int(time.strftime("%I"))
    mint = int(time.strftime("%M"))
    sec= int(time.strftime("%S"))
 

    sec_x = sec_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(sec * 6)) + center_x
    sec_y = -1 * sec_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(sec * 6)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(sec_hand, center_x, center_y, sec_x, sec_y)

    min_x = min_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(mint * 6)) + center_x
    min_y = -1 * min_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(mint   * 6)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(min_hand, center_x, center_y, min_x, min_y)

    hour_x = hour_hand_len * math.sin(math.radians(hour * 30)) + center_x
    hour_y = -1 * hour_hand_len * math.cos(math.radians(hour * 30)) + center_y
    canvas.coords(hour_hand, center_x, center_y, hour_x, hour_y)

    # call the live_clock() function again after 1000 milliseconds
    canvas.after(1000, live_clock)

# start the clock
live_clock()

# start the GUI event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: ohhh i see..... how do i make it repeat every 1000ms??

Comment: You can use the after method of the canvas widget to repeat the live_clock function every 1000ms (1 second).

Comment: isnt that what i did? i used canva.after(1000, live_clock)

Comment: Yes, you did use the after method to call the live_clock function every 1000ms. However, you need to call canvas.after again at the end of the live_clock function to schedule the next update. Otherwise, the live_clock function will only be called once, and the clock hands will not move anymore.

Comment: OKAY I GOT IT OMG TYSMM TYTYTYTYY

Comment: To clarify, `after` only schedules a function to run _once_, not repeatedly.